# Google Sheets Query

Tags: google-sheets, google-query-language

I'm creating a lottery system for some gaming community I'm a member of using Google Forms and Google Sheets.

I currently have the follow sheet that collects the form responses and highlights any that are still pending processing by a "lottery official". As shown, each record has a a maximum of 10 tickets spread across 10 columns. I need to make a sheets that shows the result of a query that tests whether the date is after a "start date", before a "end date" and one of the ticket number columns equals the "ticket number". I want to do this by having 3 input boxes then doing a query search to show results below it, however I'm unsure of how to use Google Sheet's queries. I have looked at the documentation and it's not very clear on how it structures. Hopefully someone more experience with Google Sheets / Excel could help shed some light.

I have this so far, but am completely unsure how to get it to work `=QUERY("FormResponses!A2:P1004", "select C where FormResponses!A > date A:2 AND FormResponses!A < date B:2 AND (FormResponses!F = C:2 OR FormResponses!G = C:2 OR FormResponses!H = C:2 OR FormResponses!I = C:2 OR FormResponses!I = C:2 OR FormResponses!J = C:2 OR FormResponses!K = C:2 OR FormResponses!L = C:2 OR FormResponses!M = C:2 OR FormResponses!N = C:2 OR FormResponses!0 = C:2)")`

Further more, I'm not sure if it is checking the cells from the right sheet and how to correct that within the query.

[image: https://i.gyazo.com/1ed95b1fe87bc9104a2dcc5a15b4b0c0.png]
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should fix it. On the FormResponse sheet format column A
to Date (not Date Time). Then use:

```
=query(FormResponses!A:P,"select C where A>= date '"&text(A2,"yyyy-MM-dd")&"' and A<= date '"&text(B2,"yyyy-MM-dd")&"' and (F="& C2 &" OR G="& C2 &"OR H="& C2 &" OR I="& C2 &" OR J="& C2 &"OR K="& C2 &" OR L="& C2 &" OR M="& C2 &" OR N="& C2 &" OR O="& C2 &")",1)
```

Comment: It seems to work fine in regard to selecting the right winning numbers, however the date thing is not working correctly. It doesn't seem to be selecting only the data within the date range. Is the date formatting correct? It seems to me that you are trying to turn it into a different format to that it's being compared to.

Comment: @Thomas Smyth Can you share a sample spreadsheet of your data? The dates are working on my test spreadsheet.

Comment: `https://drive.google.com/open?id=1sMCr38GoVl_JpldM6Y5odA_x22s7h9TZVFPPsJq-gXQ` This should allow you to view the form. Thanks for your help.

Comment: That address won't work. Open your spreadsheet, click Share. Click advanced and set to share with anybody with a link. Copy and post the link to share address.

Comment: `https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1sMCr38GoVl_JpldM6Y5odA_x22s7h9TZVFPPsJq-gXQ/edit?usp=sharing`

Comment: I am getting the message Sorry, the file you have requested does not exist. Here is what I tested with https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1uNOwjRWK2bBWEu8k8YIJYz2-0kluKXfumEVLK60rINA/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: I noticed that my dates are dd/mm/yyyy will that make a difference? Try this maybe?
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1sMCr38GoVl_JpldM6Y5odA_x22s7h9TZVFPPsJq-gXQ/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Yeh, I copied the same thing from your form and my date format has changed, however it still is not working as intended. The date range is simply not working.